# Handling Resize event when layout unit is resized in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, layout, primefaces, resize

I am working on my first web project and using PrimeFaces component suite for it.

I want fire a resize event when i resize the center layout unit. I have tried the code but the method in the bean class is never get called.

What am I doing wrong here? please correct me if I am wrong?

```
    <p:layout fullPage="true" resizeListner="#{resizeBean.handleResize}">
        <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" resizable="true" size="20%">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="Header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="bottom" styleClass="class-bottom" position="south"
            resizable="true" size="25%">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="Footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="left" styleClass="class-left" position="west"
            resizable="true" size="24%">
            <ui:insert name="tree">
                <ui:include src="Tree.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="addDlg" position="center">
            <ui:insert>
                <ui:include src="AddDevice.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
            <ui:insert name="centerPage">
                <ui:include src="Center.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

Here is the code for the bean class

```
@ManagedBean(name = "resize")    
public class ResizeBean implements Serializable {    
        private long width;    
        private long height;    
public void handleResize(ResizeEvent event) {    
width = event.getWidth();    
height = event.getWidth();    
System.out.println("in resize");
    }    
    public long getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public long getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know witch version of PrimeFaces you're using, but the attribute resizeListener is not found in de PrimeFaces manual. Also you gave your bean a name with the `name` attribute:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "resize")
```

So if you want to use this in your view, then refer to your given name like this:

```
#{resize.handleResize}
```

If you don't use the name attribute then you can refer to resizeBean. More info can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html

To get the resize event add a `<p:ajax>` tag in your view something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="resize" listener="#{resize.handleResize}" />
```

And now add the `<h:form>` tag around your layout and everything should work.

Complete view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:ajax event="resize" listener="#{resize.handleResize}" />
        <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" resizable="true" size="20%">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="Header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="bottom" styleClass="class-bottom" position="south"
            resizable="true" size="25%">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="Footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="left" styleClass="class-left" position="west"
            resizable="true" size="24%">
            <ui:insert name="tree">
                <ui:include src="Tree.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="addDlg" position="center">
            <ui:insert>
                <ui:include src="AddDevice.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
            <ui:insert name="centerPage">
                <ui:include src="Center.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>    
<h:/form>
```